# Magento: Target custom block via category Custom Layout Update

Tags: xml, magento

In local.xml I've added a block called "category_header", and it shows up just as intended.

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    ...
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.header" as="category_header" template="catalog/category/view_header.phtml" />
    </reference>
    ...
</catalog_category_layered>
```

In admin under "A specific category / Custom Design / Custom Layout Update" I'm trying to add a block to the "category_header" block by using the following (the newsletter block is just an example):

```
<reference name="category_header">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

That doesn't work. If I change the reference to "content" (reference name="content") it works just fine and shows up in the content block.

So my question is: What do I need to do to be able to target the category_header block?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your block to the root:

```
<reference name="root"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</reference>
```

Are you sure you want to do this, this is the very top level.

If you intentionally want to add your block to the root, then you must also output the block inside your base template files.

For example, if you're using the 1 column layout, you will need to modify the page template to otuput your block:

template/page/1column.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_header') ?>
```

the reason it works when using content as a contains is all children of the content container are automatically output, but children of the root container are not, and need manually added to your templates.

If you use any other page layouts, (2col-left etc) you will also need to add the output to each view file.

You would also need to output any blocks inside the category_header view/block:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter_header') // rename.. ?>
```

Comment: The reason I'm adding the "category_header" to the root is that I'm using the 2col-left page layout, but I want a 1 col "header" to be displayed above the left/main column - http://s11.postimg.org/da31tifpv/category_header.png. This works just fine, the problem I'm having is trying to add blocks to the "category_header" block.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that *catalog/category/view_header.phtml* contains

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newsletter') ?>
```

You can always find child blocks with:

```
<?php Zend_Debug::dump(array_keys($this->getChild())) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for my late reply, benmarks. Actually I already echo:ed the getChildHtml('newsletter') in the view_header.phtml template. Unfortunately it didn't work. I ended up calling the newsletter in the root template. Not a pretty solution, but it have to do for a couple of days until I can get back to that section.